# Цикл по массиву объектов

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, объекты

Сервер отдает JSON c массивом объектов, перебираю их обычным for.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < data[0].target.length; i++){
    if(data[0].target[i].code == Geo){
      $('.old').html(data[0].target[i].price_high + ' ' + data[0].target[i].currency);
      $('.new').html(data[0].target[i].price + ' ' + data[0].target[i].currency);
    }
 }
```

Будет-ли этот код лучше работать с конструкцией `for in`  и есть ли в ней преимущества в конкретно этой задаче?

Comment: В плане производительности так же. Но нет гарантии, что все объекты будут иметь ключи по возростанию. Может быть data[0], data[1], data[3], а data с ключом 2 не окозалось и for тут выкинет ошибку, а for in нет

Comment: @JurijJazdanov, не могли бы Вы тогда подправить данный цикл под for in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В плане производительности так же. Но нет гарантии, что все объекты(если у вас объект, а не массив) будут иметь ключи по возростанию. Может быть data[0], data[1], data[3], а data с ключом 2 не окозалось и for тут выкинет ошибку, а for in нет.

**For in не викинет ошибку**

```js
var data = {
  0: 'bla',
  1: 'bla2',
  3: 'bla3',
}

for (key in data) {
  console.log(data[key]);
}
```

**For викинет ошибку**

```js
var data = {
  0: 'bla',
  1: 'bla2',
  3: 'bla3',
}

for (ar i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i]);
}
```

**Ваш цикл в for in**

```
for(key in data[0].target){
  if(data[0].target[key].code == Geo){
    $('.old').html(data[0].target[key].price_high + ' ' + data[0].target[key].currency);
    $('.new').html(data[0].target[key].price + ' ' + data[0].target[key].currency);
  }
}
```